# Building a high-voltage, high frequency source

Tags: high-voltage, high-frequency

Can someone give an idea of how can I go about building a high voltage (20-30kV) high frequency (0-40kHz) source from a 230V, 50 Hz supply?

Is it possible to convert the input 230V, 50 Hz sine waveform through this HVHF source to HVHF waveforms of sine, square, ramp, etc.?

The current requirement is 200mA.

Comment: that sounds like you want an audio amplifier for an electrostatic speaker with slightly higher frequency range than usual, not "high frequency" by any common meaning of the word. (HF for the ITU starts at 3 MHz.)

Comment: anyway, this question is really too broad; "how do I build an amplifier"!

Comment: note that your output current spec says you want multiple kW of output power.

Comment: It’s very possible. It’s also not trivial given your specs. Basically it is a 6kW audio amplifier with a big transformer on the output. Realise that playing with such a device can kill you in many ways.

Comment: the question here might be what you're trying to build? Maybe there's some established methodology for what this would be used for, and we could point you e.g. at literature. You'd need to give us way more information on what you need this for!

Comment: please mention DC or AC ?

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd um, 40 kHz and 50 Hz do very precisely answer that question, don't they?

Comment: @MarcusMüller maybe source to be able to supply fast(high frequency response)?!

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd if you're building something that emits a sine wave, that's AC, by definition. it might be AC with offset, it might be windowed, but it's still AC.

Comment: 40 kHz is a lot easier than 0-40 kHz. 10 kHz to 40 kHz is still easier than 0 to 40 kHz. Is 0 really your bottom frequency? If so, then maybe splitting your device into two frequency ranges makes it more practical.

Answer (score 1):

> *how can I go about building a high voltage (20-30kV) high frequency
> (0-40kHz) source. HVHF waveforms of sine, square, ramp, etc.*

You would certainly use square waves to drive a HF transformer that "steps-up" a rectified and smoothed AC voltage to deliver a few thousand volts (RMS) but, at that point, the waveform would be very much a non-ideal square wave and, if you tried to generate different waveform shapes by driving it with a ramp (etc.) you would be very disappointed.

<sub>**Information:** If you were designing a HV DC supply you would take the "several kV RMS sloppy squarewave" and use diode-capacitor voltage multipliers to generate several tens to hundreds of kV DC. This is proven ground.</sub>

**So, just think about producing a 40 kHz squarewave with a peak amplitude of 30 kV.**

Let's say you wanted a rise/fall time that was about 1% of the 40 kHz period. 40 kHz has a period of 25 μs and, a rise/fall time of 1% is a time duration of 250 ns.

So, you want to change the output voltage from -30,000 volts to +30,000 volts in 250 ns; that's a dv/dt of 240,000 volts per microsecond. 1 pF capacitance between **you** and the output terminal would inject into your body this amount of current: -

$$I = C\dfrac{dv}{dt} = 240\text{ mA}$$

In other words, it's a disaster waiting to happen and you will likely hurt yourself badly if you don't realize this problem. But, it's worse than this; if you could generate a 30 kV squarewave with decent rise and falls times, virtually any localized bit of circuitry or parts of your enclosure would be sapping the output due to the small (but significant) coupling capacitance.

Think again.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome.

Not being an expert in high voltage/power electronics, I won't be able to give you full answer, but at least, I can give you some starting considerations :

- first of all, make sure that you have some connexion to mains that can supply that much power. 200mA at 30kV is 6kW, (equivalent to 26A@230V). In France, most domestic power outlets are fused at 16A, and the biggest ones (for electric ovens for exemple) are 32A. That would require a 81% efficiency, which corresponds to a good voltage converter. A function generator will probably be far less efficient, so even 32A will not be enough. Do you have a power source providing enough current? If not, I would think twice weather equipping your building with industrial grae power supply is really interesting, or if it wouldn't be better to restrict your power requirements.
- if you want to do a function generator, you usually have 3 distinct aspects :

1. generating a reference analog signal (which can be at low voltage) : this part is "easy". If you are lazy, just buy an existing low voltage function generator
2. generating a nice DC voltage above the max output voltage (often you need also a negative rail). This is rather easy on anormal function generator, but might turn out already quite tricky for yours. NB : big care should be taken to have a voltage with as little noise as possible (often linear voltage regulators are used even if they are less efficient, in order to avoid noise at the PWM frequency of hacking based regulators)
3. amplify analog signal to give it the voltage and current needed : this will also be some chalenge for that high voltages (I have no knowledge about high voltage amplifiers)

- also, take care : working at that high voltage, without restrincting current to very small ones is lethal. At 200mA, death is nearly certain (and at 30kV, your body will not have high enough resistance to diminish current to a safe level.